# How can I generate links to previous and next pages by index in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, pagination, navigation

I'm building a website in Wordpress which will include an 800+ page manual, each page of the manual being a separate web page within the site.

The urls for each page are being numbered sequentially as follows:

http://examplesite.com/manual-page-1
http://examplesite.com/manual-page-2
http://examplesite.com/manual-page-3

and so on.

At the bottom of each page, I am including a "Previous" and "Next" navigation link that will take the user back one page or forward one page depending on which one they click. [(See image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuDkb.png)

Currently, I am doing it manually for each page using HTML (ie if I'm on page 1, the target for the "Next" link is the full url of page 2.  This is obviously quite time consuming and prone to error on my part because of the vast number of pages involved.

To fix this, I've been trying to figure out how to do it in Javascript but I'm a novice and haven't been able to find any example of a script that I could modify to make it work.

In theory, what I would like to do is add some code that would take users to the next page in the manual using the url of the current page as a variable (not sure if I'm articulating that correctly).

For example, if the user is on the page with url "http://examplesite/manual-page-795 and they click "Next", the script would add a value of one to the number in the url and automatically calculate the destination for the link as "http://examplesite/manual-page-796".  Conversely, if they click on "Previous" there would be a script that would subtract a value of one from the number in the url and automatically take them to "http://examplesite/manual-page-794.

I have also included a "go to page" input box with a submit button at the bottom of each page using Javascript to take the user to the appropriate page based on their input.  [(See image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZrpV.png) The code that I have used to do this is as follows:

**HTML for the form and button:**

```html
<center><div class="div1"><input type="text" value="" id="input" placeholder="Go To Page Number..."/></div>
<div class="div2"><button type="button" id="button" button="" class="myButton">Submit</button></div></center>
```

**Javascript to take the user to the correct URL based on the number they input:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://examplesite.com/manual-page-"+inputvalue);

    });
});
</script>
```

This works great and what I am hoping to do is use something similar for the "Previous" and "Next" navigation links but instead of calculating the destination of the URL based on the user's text input, the destination would be calculated based on number in the url of the current page plus or minus one digit.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I could go about doing this or point in a direction that would help me figure this out I would truly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this with HTML _or_ JavaScript. WordPress is a powerful CMS, and as such can generate this type of thing for you (either with the correct plugin configuration or via [custom PHP templating](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157760/how-to-get-link-and-title-of-next-and-previous-post-on-single-page)). You shouldn't be trying to do it on the front end.

Comment: However, if you do want to try JavaScript, you'll need to research how to get the current URL, parse the path string, modify it appropriately, then inject that into the page. You need to make an effort and show your work, asking more specific questions. SO isn't a place to ask for broad suggestions or external resources. Good luck.

Comment: One further suggestion--a manual organized by nothing but page numbers may not be user-friendly, and logical grouping of pages into categories (correlating to chapters or topics) might yield a better result. It would also get you closer to the kind of navigation you're after with less custom programming.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood.  I realize my question was a bit open ended.  I have modified it to show the work that I have done for a script that uses a variable and takes the user to a particular url based on their text input.  I am hoping that I could use something similar for the "Next" and "Previous" links but instead of relying on user input, the destination would be automatically calculated using the url of the current page plus or minus one digit in the url name.

Comment: @isherwood.  Also, in terms of the organization of the manual, what I am doing is taking a hard copy of a physical publication that my dad wrote and putting it online for him.  The hard copy has a table of contents and is organized into chapters so I have included a drop down table of contents on the site with links to all chapters and subheadings as well as a search function that allows the user to input their search and returns a drop down result with snippets of all the instances of the particular term.  Not sure if this was the best way to do it but the result is user friendly.

Comment: I understand your mission. See my second comment for a general direction. The table of contents should be a site-level menu, in my opinion (as a UX specialist), and not something embedded in a page that requires a separate navigation action. With good categorization this would be fairly trivial to accomplish.